# How to fix bugs in custom block validation?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

Help find errors. I don't even understand the error
Most likely a problem with save.js, but I'm just learning and nothing helps me.

**save.js:**

```
import { useBlockProps, RichText, MediaUpload } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

export default function save({ attributes }) {
   const { images } = attributes;

   const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
   // return <div {...blockProps}>{attributes.message}</div>;
   return (
    //{attributes.message}</div>
    <div {...useBlockProps}>
        <button className="swiper_button button_prev">
            <i class="icofont-rounded-left"></i>
        </button>
        <button className="swiper_button button_next">
            <i class="icofont-rounded-right"></i>
        </button>

        {JSON.stringify(attributes)}

        {images.map((element, index) => (
            <div class="slider_container active" key={index}>
                <div className="sliders_image">
                    <img src={element.imageUrl} alt={element.imageAlt} />
                    
                </div>
                <div class="sliders_text">
                    <RichText.Content tagName="p" value={element.text1} />
                    <RichText.Content tagName="p" value={element.text2} />
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);

}
```

**edit.js:**

```
    import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";

import { useBlockProps, MediaUpload, RichText } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { TextControl, Button } from "@wordpress/components";
import "./editor.scss";

/**
 * The edit function describes the structure of your block in the context of the
 * editor. This represents what the editor will render when the block is used.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#edit
 *
 * @return {WPElement} Element to render.
 */
export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes, isSelected }) {
    const { images } = attributes;
    const addListItem = (newListItem) =>
        setAttributes({ images: [...images, newListItem] });

    // Bad - the images from the existing attribute is modified directly to add the new images item:

    const updateImage = (index, newImage) => {
        const { images } = attributes;
        const updatedImages = [...images];
        updatedImages[index] = { ...updatedImages[index], ...newImage };
        setAttributes({ images: updatedImages });
        console.log('Updated Images:', updatedImages);
    };

    const setImageAttributes = (id, media) => {
        if (!media || !media.url) {
          updateImage(id, {
            imageUrl: null,
            imageId: null,
            imageAlt: null,
          });
        } else {
          updateImage(id, {
            imageUrl: media.url,
            imageId: media.id,
            imageAlt: media.alt || '',
          });
        }
      };
      
  
    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}>
            <button className="swiper_button button_prev">
                <i class="icofont-rounded-left"></i>
            </button>
            <button className="swiper_button button_next">
                <i class="icofont-rounded-right"></i>
            </button>
    
            {images.map((element, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="slider_container active">
                    <div className="sliders_image">
                        <MediaUpload
                            onSelect={(media) =>
                                setImageAttributes(index, {
                                    url: media.url,
                                    alt: media?.alt
                                })
                            }
                            type="image"
                            value={element.imageId}
                            render={({ open }) => (
                                <Button onClick={open}>
                                    <div class="text_hover">
                                        {element.imageUrl ? "Change Image" : "Select Image"}
                                    </div>
                                    {element.imageUrl && (
                                        <img src={element.imageUrl} alt={element.imageAlt} />
                                    )}
                                </Button>
                            )}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="sliders_text">
                        <RichText
                            tagName="p"
                            value={element.text1}
                            onChange={(newText1) => updateImage(index, { text1: newText1 })}
                        />

                        <RichText
                            tagName="p"
                            value={element.text2}
                            onChange={(newText2) => updateImage(index, { text2: newText2 })}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}

            {/* Add a button to add a new image */}
            <button
                class="editor-add-button"
                onClick={() =>
                    addListItem({
                        "imageUrl": "",
                        "imageId": "",
                        "imageAlt": "",
                        "text1": "Title",
                        "text2": "Subtitle"
                    })
                }
            >
                Folie hinzufügen
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**block.json:**

```
{
"$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
"apiVersion": 3,
"name": "create-block/swiper",
"version": "0.1.0",
"title": "Swiper",
"category": "widgets",
"icon": "smiley",
"description": "Example block scaffolded with Create Block tool.",
"example": {},
"supports": {
    "html": false
},
"attributes": {
    "images": {
        "type": "array",
        "source": "query",
        "default": [
            {
                "imageUrl": "",
                "imageAlt": "",
                "imageId": "",
                "text1": "Title",
                "text2": "Subtitle"
            }
        ],

        "query": {
            "imageUrl": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "imageAlt": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "imageId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "text1": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "text2": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
},
"textdomain": "swiper",
"editorScript": "file:./index.js",
"editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
"style": "file:./style-index.css",

"viewScript": "file:./view.js"}
```

**error:**

```
logger.js:17 Block validation: Block validation failed for `create-block/swiper` ({name: 'create-block/swiper', icon: {…}, keywords: Array(0), attributes: {…}, providesContext: {…}, …}).

Content generated by `save` function:

    <div><button class="swiper_button button_prev"><i class="icofont-rounded-left"></i></button><button class="swiper_button button_next"><i class="icofont-rounded-right"></i></button>{"images":[]}</div>

Content retrieved from post body:

    <div><button class="swiper_button button_prev"><i class="icofont-rounded-left"></i></button><button class="swiper_button button_next"><i class="icofont-rounded-right"></i></button>{"images":[{"imageUrl":"https://localhost/doctor.local/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/Download-1.jpeg","imageAlt":"","text1":"Titlegfh jghf fgh jfghj fg","text2":"Subtitlehj fghj fghj gfhj fghj fghj"}]}<div class="slider_container active"><div class="sliders_image"><img src="https://localhost/doctor.local/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/Download-1.jpeg" alt=""/></div><div class="sliders_text"><p>Titlegfh jghf fgh jfghj fg</p><p>Subtitlehj fghj fghj gfhj fghj fghj</p></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've made a really good effort on setting up a block to add multiple images with buttons/text. I recommend reviewing the source code for the core [Gallery Block JSON](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/gallery/block.json) as an example of setting up `attributes.images` as an array using query.

**Steps to resolve Block Validation error**

1. In `block.json`, your `attributes.images` is missing [a selector for the query](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#value-source) to work. In `save.js`, the images are contained within `<div className="slider_container" ...>`, so you can use `.slider_container` as the selector, eg:

**block.json**

```json
"attributes": {
        "images": {
            "type": "array",
            "source": "query",
            "selector": ".slider_container", // added
            "default":[] // added
            ...
```

2. For the query to load the correct attributes for the images, the *selector* and *attribute* must find a valid match in the saved content. As `attributes.imageUrl` will be the value of `<img src="{imageUrl}"...>`, the selector is *img* and the attribute is *src*, eg:

```json
"query": {
    "imageUrl": {
        "type": "string",
        "source": "attribute",
        "selector": ".sliders_image img", // updated
        "attribute": "src"
    },
...
```

Update `query.imageAlt` and `query.imageId` in the same way with the attribute as *alt* and *id* respectively.

4. For the `text1` and `text2`, add a className in `save()` to be used [as the selector](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#query-source) for the query in `block.json`:

**save.js**

```
...
<div className="sliders_text">
    <RichText.Content className="text1" tagName="p" value={element.text1} />
    <RichText.Content className="text2" tagName="p" value={element.text2} />
</div>
...
```

**block.json**

```json
"query": {
    ...
    "text1": {
        "type": "string",
        "source": "html", // added
        "selector": ".sliders_text .text1" // added
        },
    "text2": {
        "type": "string",
        "source": "html", // added
        "selector": ".sliders_text .text2" // added
    }
...
```

5. The block validation error indicates the query cannot find the right source to map to the attributes. This can be resolved by changing the images to be mapped inside `.slider_container` , eg:

**save.js**

```js
<div className="slider_container active" >
    {images.map((element, index) => (
        <div className="sliders_image" key={index}>
            <img src={element.imageUrl} alt={element.imageAlt} />
        </div>
        ...
    ))}
</div>
```

Also, in both your `edit.js` and `save.js`, the CSS class is sometimes applied as `class="...`; it should always be `className="...` as "class" is a reserved word. Although this does not cause the block validation error, it should be corrected as its present when debugged and will reduce the "noise" and enable you to see the real issues.

Hope this helps guide you in the right direction with building your block and resolving the error.